# gcc optimizations cause app to fail

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization, fast-math

I'm having a real strange problem using GCC for ARM with the optimizations turned on. 
Compiling my C++ application without the optimizations produces an executable that 
at runtime outputs the expected results. As soon as I turn on the 
optimizations - that is -O1 - my application fails to produce the expected results.
I tried for a couple of days to spot the problem but I'm clueless.
I eliminated any uninitialized variables from my code, I corrected the spots where 
strict aliasing could cause problems but still I do not have the proper results.

I'm using GCC 4.2.0 for ARM(the processor is an ARM926ej-s) and running the app 
on a Montavista Linux distribution.

Below are the flags I'm using:

```
-O1 -fno-unroll-loops fno-merge-constants -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-toplevel-reorder \
-fno-defer-pop -fno-function-cse -Wuninitialized -Wstrict-aliasing=3 -Wstrict-overflow=3 \
-fsigned-char -march=armv5te -mtune=arm926ej-s -ffast-math
```

As soon as I strip the -O1 flag and recompile/relink the application I get the proper output results. As you can see from the flags I tried to disable any optimization I thought it might cause problems but still no luck.

Does anyone have any pointers on how I could further tackle this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What is "the expected result" ? Do you get a logic error as in wrong "if" branch chosen, or wrong calculations ? Are you sure all your variables are correctly initialized ?

Comment: The calculations are wrong. Yes, I'm pretty sure all the variables are correctly initialized.

Comment: That's like saying "I'm pretty sure my code is correct, so why doesn't it work?" ;)

Comment: @jalf: No that's like saying "I really checked that all my variables are correctly initialized and have proper default values". I'm pretty sure the code is not correct in other respect in the described specific scenario.

Comment: my point is just that "pretty sure" isn't really useful. If you're less than 100% sure, then it's still a potential error source that shouldn't be discounted. :) When debugging, there's only "absolutely sure" and "not sure" ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you say "optimization breaks my program", it is 99.9% your *programm* that is broken. Enabling optimizations only *uncovers* the faults in your code.

You should also go easy on the optimization options. Only in very specific circumstances will you need anything else beyond the standard options -O0, -O2, -O3 and perhaps -Os. If you feel you *do* need more specific settings than that, heed the mantra of optimizations:

**Measure, optimize, measure.**

*Never* go by "gut feeling" here. Prove that a certain non-standard optimization option does significantly benefit your application, *and understand why* (i.e., understand exactly what that option does, and why it affects your code).

This is not a good place to navigate blindfolded.

And seeing how you use the most defensive option (-O1), then disable half a dozen optimizations, and *then* add -ffast-math, leads me to assume you're currently doing just that.

Well, perhaps one-eyed.

But the bottom line is: If enabling optimization breaks your code, it's most likely your code's fault.

**EDIT:** I just found this in the GCC manual:

> `-ffast-math`: This option should never be turned on by any -O option
>    since it can result in incorrect output for programs which depend on
>   an exact implementation of IEEE or ISO rules/specifications for math
>   functions.

This does say, basically, that your `-O1 -ffast-math` could indeed break *correct* code. However, even if taking away `-ffast-math` removes your current problem, you should at least have an idea *why*. Otherwise you might merely exchange your problem *now* with a problem at a more inconvenient moment *later* (like, when your product breaks at your client's location). Is it really `-ffast-math` that was the problem, or do you have broken math code that is *uncovered* by `-ffast-math`?

Comment: Thanks for the slap! That was it. I failed to see the "which depend on an exact implementation of IEEE or ISO rules/specifications for math functions" when checking that flag in the documentation.

Comment: It's great you found the issue; but you should really still try to find out which code is sensitive to -ffast-math (it may be a library you use).  The senstive code is probably numerically instable and at the very least is doing sensitive to changes in ways you don't immediately expect.

Comment: @Eamon Nerbonne: you are perfectly right and that's what will keep me busy for the next couple of days.

Answer (score 2):

`-ffast-math` should be avoided if possible. Just use `-O1` for now and drop all the other optimisation switches. If you still see problems then it's time to start debugging.

Comment: +1: `-ffast-math` is a prime candidate.  It allows the compiler to make floating-point substitutions that aren't guaranteed to give identical results.

Comment: +1: but I accepted the other answer as I needed the slap on the back of my head

Comment: Actually, my recommendation is usually the reverse: if turning on -ffast-math affects the outcome of your program significantly, you probably have numerically instable code you should fix (and be happy it was this easy to find!)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to get more specific than "you probably have a bug".

There are two scenarios where enabling optimizations changes the semantics of the program:

- there is a bug in the compiler, or
- there is a bug in your code.

The latter is probably the most likely. Specifically, you probably rely on Undefined Behavior somewhere in your program. You rely on something that just so happen to be true when you compile using *this* compiler on *this* computer with *these* compiler flags, but which isn't guaranteed by the language. And so, when you enable optimizations, GCC is under no obligation to preserve that behavior.

Show us your code. Or step through it in the debugger until you get to the point where things go wrong.

I can't be any more specific. It might be a dangling pointer, uninitialized variables, breaking the aliasing rules, or even just doing one of the many things that yield undefined results (like `i = i++`)

Comment: I cannot show the code. And you're probably right, there is a bug in the code which is triggered by a combination of flags. I debugged the app and I did not spot the problem(that does not mean of course that I should stop debugging) ... I just wanted to know if there are known problems combining the flags or if anyone encountered such a scenario I'm describing.

Comment: A lot of people have encountered such a scenario. But like I said, it generally only happens if your code violates some assumption made by the compiler, either because the compiler's assumptions are wrong (buggy compiler) or because you're doing things that aren't well-defined by the language (so the compiler is right to make the assumptions it makes, your code just doesn't satisfy them because it relies on undefined behavior. Unfortunately, there are *a lot* of things you might do in C that look safe, but are actually undefined.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to make a minimal test case.** Rewrite the program, removing things that don't affect the error.  It's likely that you'll discover the bug yourself in the process, but if you don't, you should have a one-screen example program you *can* post.

Incidentally, *if*, as others have speculated, it is `-ffast-math` which causes your trouble (i.e. compiling with just `-O1` works fine), then it is likely you have some math in there you should rewrite anyhow.  It's a bit of an over-simplification, but `-ffast-math` permits the compiler to essentially rearrange computations as you could abstract mathematical numbers - even though doing so on real hardware may cause slightly different results since floating point numbers aren't exact.  Relying on that kind of floating point detail is likely to be unintentional.

If you want to understand the bug, a minimal test-case is critical in any case.